# 30 Day stats with MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am currently trying to create a ranking system with mongodb, I have stats entries that shall be recognised for 30 days and then deleted, I have 3 questions in this, the first one, how can I count all the stats of the last 30 days together in a aggregation operation?

This is my data structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bd28682a353f11bb30ab9fe"),
"UUID" : "d98e8f70-314f-4858-ad43-7775b2564e38",
"rank" : -1,
"stats" : [ 
    { 
        "timestamp": 1198334588378,
        "stat_kills" : 1.0,
        "stat_deaths": 4.0,
        "points" : 10
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp": 1198334588378,
        "stat_kills" : 8.0,
        "stat_deaths": 1.0,
        "points" : 26
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp": 1198334588378,
        "stat_kills" : 5.0,
        "stat_deaths": 6.0,
        "points" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "timestamp": 1198334588378,
        "stat_items_pickedup" : 8.0,
        "stat_kills" : 7.0,
        "stat_deaths": 3.0,
        "points" : 34
    }
]
}
```

I have an aggregation query that counts all the points and it looks like this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
[
    {
        $match: {
            "UUID" : "d98e8f70-314f-4858-ad43-7775b2564e38"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$stats"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id:"$UUID", points: {$sum : "$stats.points"}
        }
    },

]
);
```

The current result is:

```
  {"_id" : "d98e8f70-314f-4858-ad43-7775b2564e38", "points" : 74}
```

the desired result is:

```
{
"UUID":"d98e8f70-314f-4858-ad43-7775b2564e38", 
"points":74,
"stat_kills":(sum of all kills),
"stat_death" : (sum of all deaths),
"stat_items_pickedup": (sum of all items picked up)
}
```

The problem is I don't know all the fields to add up, they are always different, and they may be 10 field but they also may be 2 or only 1 stats field, is there a way in aggregation to achieve this? The database structure is not final so if it needs changing you can and I will adopt the changes, my second question is how can I delete a list entry that is older then 30 days, the timestamp is java system.currenttimemilis so I can run an aggregation search on a java client but how can I delete list entries I aggregation? I have no code there because I have no idea how to do this, the 3d question is how can I get the rank for a given document based on all the points he has? the more points he has the better rank he shall get, so, can I insert the rank or maybe a points field in the root document with the uuid ore shall I always run a aggregation for this? Tanks for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: {
            path : "$stats"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "stats.timestamp": {
                $gte: (Math.round(new Date().getTime()) - 86400000*30)
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$UUID",
            stat_kills: {
                $sum: "$stats.stat_kills"
            },
            stat_deaths: {
                $sum: "$stats.stat_deaths"
            },
            points: {
                $sum: "$stats.points"
            },
            "rank": {
                $first: "$rank"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

I hope this will help you.
If you have any question feel free to ask.

Comment: This query will return you selected stats keys sum for last 30 days groped by `UUID`